# Can i use matplotlibs imshow without cmap/color mapping?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hi i'am new to python and i try to see some images from CT scans that are grayscale.Matplotlibs imshow has by default the option 'viridis' on cmap if it takes an MxN(CT image) array(image) as input.I use is there anyway to see the images as they are in grayscale without the color map(cmap)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the argument `cmap='gray'`.
Assuming that you image is a matrix called arr, you can use:

```
plt.imshow(arr, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html you may want to add this guide to the cmaps